# How can I sort Julius files in the combined javascript file in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Using Yesod scaffolding site, is there a reason why default-layout.julius is rendered after my other julius files in the generated "autogen-XXX.js"?

Is there a way to change that order, so that default-layout.julius is rendered first?

Comment: I found a solution to my problem: create a additional julius file containing the code I put in default-layout.julius, and add the corresponding widget to all the Handler... But I'm still interested by another solution, especially if I can understand better how Yesod works :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Widget` is essentially just a `WriterT` transformer, and when you add a template, it gets appended after all other templates previously added. If you look in [the scaffold's implementation of `defaultLayout`](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-scaffold/blob/cd13c709afbd678dd1308eb0e73d110b9548419f/Foundation.hs#L63), you can see that it's just using `widgetFile` on `default-layout`. This ends up including the `hamlet` portion before the `julius` portion, and the `hamlet` portion includes the entirety of the individual page's widget (if that makes sense... it's really early over here right now).

Simple solution: put the `default-layout.julius` content into another file (e.g., `default-layout-early.julius`), and then add `$(widgetFile "default-layout-early")` before "default-layout". That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this complete answer. The solution and the explanation are perfect :-).